# Is it possible to send a message from my mobile phone to my computer using TCP and the computer's IP?

Tags: sockets, java-me, tcp

I want to use my computer's IP address to send a message using socket connection between them. My mob acts as the client and my computer , as a server. I tried this applictaion using a J2ME emuator and I was able to do that but when I deployed the app to my phone and tested it, it did not work at,it just asked me whether I want to connect to the network and when I responded "Yes" it stayed idle and nothing else happened. I received no response at all in my computer. Anyone know why it's not working?

Thanks in adv

Comment: The simple answer to your vague question is yes, but if you really want help, provide some of your code... put a little more effort in it.. you'll find that people will help you much faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's technically possible. However, keep in mind that your CellPhone **must** have an IP route to your computer (your computer probably needs a public IP address, or your cell phone and your computer must be in the same **WIFI** network).

Comment: My computer does have a public IP address, however I am not using wifi but WAP for mobile phone and the web for my computer..

Comment: Then you should be able to reach your computer with your cell phone. Do post some code to see if there is something wrong with it...